# Get static 404 error though css files are correctly configured

Tags: css, django

I loaded static and configured finely the nested directory structure for `bootstrap.min.css`. However, it unexpectedly throws an error:

```
"GET /static/forums/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1685
```

The index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Forum Home Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "forums/bootstrap.min.css" %}" />
  </head>
```

The css was not loaded ant it displayed:

[image]

The app forums' file structure:

```
forums
├── __init__.py
├── admin.py
├── apps.py
├── migrations
│   └── __init__.py
├── models.py
├── static
│   └── forums
│       └── bootstrap.min.css
├── templates
│   └── forums
│       └── index.html
├── tests.py
├── urls.py
└── views.py
```

And the setting.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'forum.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'forums/templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'forum.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), #notice the comma
)
```

If I comment out `STATICFILES_DIRS` it reports the same error.

What might be the problem in my code?

Comment: please try python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/me/Desktop/Django/forum/static'`

Comment: Are you using `runserver` in development with `DEBUG=True`? Is `'forums'` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Please show the layout of the project directory as well.

Comment: If DEBUG=True, add following to urls.py `+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

Comment: I forgot to add `forums` to `INSTALLED_APPS`, could you please transmit your comment to answer. @Alasdair

Comment: Glad that solved the problem. Note that you shouldn't post sensitive info like `SECRET_KEY`. Make sure you change it before you deploy your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `forums/bootstrap.min.css` file is in the `static` directory of your `forums` app.

Therefore you need to include `'forums'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` so that the app directories staticfiles finder can find it.

When you add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")` to `STATICFILES_DIRS`, Django will also look in the static directory of your *project*. The `No such file or directory` error suggests that this directory doesn't exist. To stop the error when running `collectstatic` you can either create the directory or remove it from `STATICFILES_DIRS`.

Comment: `static` may be invented to save life but it eventually haunting complicated. When I comment out, it report ` STATIC_ROOT setting to a filesystem path.`, I'd like to forget it and continue my learning.

Comment: Since you have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`,  the `runserver` will take care of serving static files for you. You don't have to set `STATIC_ROOT` or run `collectstatic` until you deploy your project into production.

Answer (score 1):

If `DEBUG=True` then un urls.py add to `urlpatterns`

```
urlpatterns = [....] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

And for static URL which do have a prefix,  STATICFILES_DIRS could be as below

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   # ...
   ("forums", os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../static/forums/")),
]
```

Comment: The OP already has `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in their `INSTALLED_APPS`, therefore they shouldn't need to use `+= static(...)` in their `urls.py`.